# how to use to-report in multiple procedures in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm writing a NetLogo program and I'm facing an issue.

I have 'to-report' the procedure and it reports a value. In this report, I take input from the user.
But I want to use the reported value(output) in multiple other procedures.

```
to-report initial-goat
    let goats-number read-from-string user-input "How many goats are there ?"
    while [goats-number > 100] [set goats-number read-from-string user-input "Please enter a value below or equal to 100 "] 
    report goats-number
end

to goat-create
   create-turtles initial-goat
end

to calculate
  let x initial-goat
  let alive count turtles
  let dead (x - alive)
end
```

Here when I use the procedures to calculate and goat-create the program asks the user two times to give input. how to avoid this?
thanks.
best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, assuming that the calculate procedure runs each time step, your code will ask for the initial goats many times. As this information never changes, you should store it in a variable. There are two options.

If you want to use a question format, then:

```
globals [initial-goat]

to get-initial-goat
    set goats-number read-from-string user-input "How many goats are there ?"
    while [goats-number > 100] [set goats-number read-from-string user-input "Please enter a value below or equal to 100 "] 
end

to goat-create
   create-turtles initial-goat
end

to calculate
  let alive count turtles
  let dead (initial-goat - alive)
end
```

But the more usual way to do something like this is to simply have a slider on the interface rather than ask a question. You would have a slider (with upper limit 100) and then you only need:

```
to goat-create
   create-turtles initial-goat
end

to calculate
  let alive count turtles
  let dead (initial-goat - alive)
end
```